# Two different table in parallel in a asp.net web

Tags: asp.net, css-float

i have a table in asp.net web the code is as under

```
<table class="gridtable">
<tr>
<th>Info Header 1</th><th>Info Header 2</th><th>Info Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Text 1A</td><td>Text 1B</td><td>Text 1C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Text 2A</td><td>Text 2B</td><td>Text 2C</td>
</tr>
</table>

style is as under
<style type="text/css">
table.gridtable {
font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
color:#333333;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #666666;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.gridtable th {
border-width: 1px;
padding: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #666666;
background-color: #dedede;
}
table.gridtable td {
border-width: 1px;
padding: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #666666;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

now i want two different tables which is displayed in parallel but different table the formatting also will be different

one table displays here in web page and the second table displays here on the web
how can i do that.

Comment: *one table displays here in web page and the second table displays here on the web* : Now what does that mean?

Comment: two tables in line with a gap between them

Answer (score 0):

(1) side-by-side tables:

Add `float:left` to your `table.gridtable {` css.

(2) gap between them:

Add `margin: 0px 2px` to `table.gridtable {` css. This will give a gap of 2 pixels.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8kKhL/1/

**Note**: Make sure the cumulative widths of your tables do not exceed the page width to avoid ugly horizontal scroll or wrapping.

Comment: i checked the jsfiddle the layout which i required was not like this both should come in a line horizontal and not vertical

Comment: @user3051436: Did you try re-sizing the panes in the fiddle? And more importantly did you read my answer carefully? Did you read the note at the end of my answer?